# what is the difference between <osgi:reference> and <osgi:service> in spring DM

Tags: osgi, equinox, spring-dm

what is the difference between `<osgi:reference>` and `<osgi:service>` in the xml config file of spring DM.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[`<osgi:reference>`](http://static.springsource.org/osgi/docs/current/reference/html/service-registry.html#service-registry:refs) can be used to **get** a reference to existing OSGi service so your bean can use it.

[`<osgi:service>`](http://static.springsource.org/osgi/docs/current/reference/html/service-registry.html#service-registry:export) can be used to **export** a bean as an OSGi service so it can be used by others.